# Get class hint after query data by sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, pycharm, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm using pycharm IDE.

I am using `sqlalchemy` to query my data in db, but how to get model's attributes hint when coding ?

[image: Can't get model's attribute hint]

> Can't get model's attribute hint

It didn't show hint of mode's attribute like `id` 、 `name` 、`age`、`salary` .

`session.query(Users).all()` return `Any` type not `list[Users]`

[image: return Any instead of list[Users]]

How to let data show attribute hint after sqlalchemy query ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Long story short: you can explicilty [set the type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) for the instances returned by SQLAlchemy methods:

```
import typing

users: typing.List[Users] = session.query(Users).all()
for user in users:
    user.  # PyCharm will show the attributes of the class
```

It is rather difficult to identify the result type of methods like `Query.all()` for an IDE (though it may be obvious for us) because the type is calculated on runtime. The same method may be used with another SQLAlchemy model and the result type will be another.

PyCharm provides hints based on return types of functions and methods (if they are explicitly defined using `typing`) and sometimes tries to guess the type of the return value:

```
def new_user(datetime_now, swin_count, gym_count):
    """The result of this function will be identified as Users by PyCharm"""
    return Users(datetime_now, swin_count, gym_count)
```

But the result type of `Query.all()` is too much for it.